# A strange array error-occurs only on device

Tags: swift

Using simulator this works good and results are as expected , but on device I get error on *compilation* :

```
//data is array, where each element is array of strings
  for array in data
        {
            let firstChar=array[0]  //error here on device compilation only
```

error :
**ambiguous use of subscript**

**EDIT:**

```
 data.removeAllObjects()
        data=tdata.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
```

//Where tdata is `NSArray`

Comment: What type have you defined `data` as?

Comment: data is NSArray...

Comment: wait, check my edit

Comment: show the definition of `data`. what version of swift / Xcode are you using. why are you trying to index characters?

Comment: Ok , thanks. Please check my edit again.

Comment: how do you expect the compiler to know the data type of the objects in the array ?

Comment: @max_ this gives another error. . Wain , I am not sure I get your point, can you please explain ? You have data which is mutable array, then you want to get the first object..

Comment: How the compiler supposed to infer the type of `firstChar`? All it knows it is that there is an NSMutableArray full of `stuff`, without knowing anything about the contents' type

Comment: Thats right, but when I tried :   "  for array in data as! NSMutableArray" I got error too. Also it complies on the simulator for some reason..

Comment: Even knowing it's an `NSMutableArray`, that doesn't tell it anything about the contents, which is what `firstChar`'s type is dependent on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to solve this with :

```
        var thisArray:NSMutableArray=[]
        thisArray=array.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
        let firstChar=thisArray[0]
```

This way the compiler knows "thisArray" is some mutable array .